# Is one allowed to learn Torah/ make Brachos in front of a dog?

Tags: torah-study, animals

I know one is allowed to own a dog, and *mistama* the dog moves around the house wherever it wants, plops down wherever etc.

Was wondering if one is allowed to learn Torah/ daven/ make brachos in the presence of a dog?

Comment: I think that what you may have read / heard may be specific to not davening Amidah before a dog, and it may be b/c of the smell.

Comment: Why do you assume one cannot?

Comment: It should be ok, unless the dog(and definitely the dog, not just someone blaming him) creates an offensive, unbearable smell in the area.

Answer (score 1):

When discussing the Halachos of not saying Brachos in front of different 'disgusting' things, the Seforim only mention that a pig has an assumed status of always being dirty with excrement. The implication of that is that most other animals do not have a 'default' status of bing being dirty with regards to Brachos and the like. Of course, if the animal is dirty/smelly/etc., then the 'default' cleanliness would not be applicable.

One such example brought down Lehalachah regardng the uncleanliness of a pig is the [Chayei Adam, last sentence of 3:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam.3.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) (translation my own):

> ופי חזיר דינו כצואה עוברת אפילו עולה מן הנהר אין הרחצה מועיל לו ודינו
>   כצואה עוברת
>
> The mouth of a pig is always considered like feces passing before you,
>   even when it just arrises from a river, since washing does not help
>   it, and therefore it is always considered like feces passing before
>   you.

Comment: See brachot 25a :  א"ר פפא פי חזיר כצואה עוברת דמי פשיטא לא צריכא אע"ג דסליק מנהרא א"ר

Answer (score 1):

For davening, Rav Yair Wassertal is of the opinion ([here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/32074)) that it is technically permitted, but inadvisable, as it may distract from having the proper concentration.  He does however quote the Chelkas Ya'akov (OC 34) who says that a dog should not be brought into a Beit Haknesset.

I don't have time to read/summarize them now, but see [here](https://www.hidabroot.org/question/258068), [here](http://www.habad.org.il/Questions/Item.asp?CategoryID=68&ArticleID=2135), [here](http://www.chabad.org.il/Questions/Item.asp?ArticleID=3534&CategoryID=68), and [here](http://halachayomit.co.il/he/default.aspx?HalachaID=640), among other sources.